# WinForms - How to loop through tabcontrol's tabpages that have custom pages and system.windows.forms tabpages?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I've made some pre-built tab pages that inherit from the systems.windows.forms.tabpage class to help cluster relevant elements and improve flexibility and readability. The problem is that in doing this, I made it so that I can't loop through the tabcontrol's pages when I want that specific tabpage layout by using foreach. I get the following error:

"System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' to type 'GraphicProject.ProductionTabPage'.'"

What are some of the options I have to get fix this issue that allow me to continue making these pre-built components? Code below.

Form Designer Code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlowCal_Time_Analyzer
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        
        
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage());
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(new ProductionTabPage());
            foreach (ProductionTabPage PTG in tabControl1.TabPages) //failure happens here on first element
            {
                PTG.Initialize();
            }
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}
```

TabPage Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using System.Threading;

namespace FlowCal_Time_Analyzer
{
    class ProductionTabPage : TabPage
    {
        private Button GetProductionDataButton = new Button();
        private DateTimePicker ProductionDatePicker = new DateTimePicker();
        private DateTime m_selectedDate;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.ProductionDatePicker.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.ProductionDatePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
            this.ProductionDatePicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(83,4);
            this.ProductionDatePicker.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.ProductionDatePicker.Name = "GraphDatePicker";
            this.ProductionDatePicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 20);
            this.ProductionDatePicker.TabIndex = 1;
            this.ProductionDatePicker.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged);
            this.ProductionDatePicker.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.GraphDatePicker_MouseUp);

            this.GetProductionDataButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
            this.GetProductionDataButton.Name = "GetProductionDataButton";
            this.GetProductionDataButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.GetProductionDataButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.GetProductionDataButton.Text = "Get Device Count";
            this.GetProductionDataButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.GetProductionDataButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.GetProductionDataButton_Click);

            this.Controls.Add(ProductionDatePicker);
            this.Controls.Add(GetProductionDataButton);


        }


        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_selectedDate = ProductionDatePicker.Value.Date;
        }

        private void GraphDatePicker_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ProductionDatePicker.Select();
            SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
        }

        private void GetProductionDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBProductionModule dB_Production = new DBProductionModule();
            dB_Production.GetProductionData(m_selectedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages) { if (tp is ProductionTabPage ) { ((ProductionTabPage)tp).Initialize();)`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! But I'm a bit confused on why this worked. Isn't this just doing the same implied cast as I initially specified in my code, just reversed? Does it work because the type is known to be the productiontabpage, or does it work because the tabpage is what the productiontabpage inherits?

Comment: the latter. The terminology of calling it casting __up__  or __down__  is not clear but only one works, from the specialized to the more basic type ;-)